# Proof of Recursion involving Higher Order Derivative of a Composite Function

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

Let two $n+1$ differentiable real functions $f$ and $u$, then the goal of the proof is:

\begin{equation}
    D^{n}(f \circ u) = \sum_{p=1}^{n}(D^{p}f \circ u)H_{p}^{n}(u)
    \label{hypothesis}
\end{equation}

Where $H_p^{n}(u)$ obeys the following:

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        H_1^n(u) &= D^nu\\
        H_n^n(u) &= (Du)^n\\
        H_0^n(u) &= 0\\
        H_{n+1}^n &= 0
    \end{aligned}
\label{assumption_h}
\end{equation}

---

The first thing I want is to "prove" a recursion involving $H$ as a lemma. I'm not sure if this counts as a proof, so that is why I wrote it with quotation marks.

Subgoal:

\begin{equation}
H_p^{n+1}(u) = DuH_{p-1}^n(u)+DH_p^n(u)
\label{recursion}
\end{equation}

I will attempt it by induction

Choose $f = P_a: x \mapsto x^a$

$$D^n(P_a \circ u) = \sum_{p=1}^{n}(D^{p}P_{a-p} \circ u)H_{p}^{n}(u)$$

$$D^{n+1}(P_a \circ u) = D(D^n(P_a \circ u)) = D\left[\sum_{p=1}^{n}(D^{p}P_a \circ u)H_{p}^{n}(u)\right]$$

Product rule

$$=\sum_{p=1}^{n}(D^{p+1}P_a \circ u)(Du)H_{p}^{n}(u) + \sum_{p=1}^{n}(D^{p}P_a \circ u)DH_{p}^{n}(u)$$

Using the notation $a^\bar{n}$ to indicate $a(a-1)...(a-n)$ and using the fact $D^bP_a = a^{b-1}P_{a-b}(x)$

$$=\sum_{p=1}^{n}a^\bar{p}P_{a-(p+1)}(u)DuH_p^n(u) + \sum_{p=1}^{n}a^\bar{p-1}P_{a-p}DH_p^n(u)$$

Changing the index on the first summand: $p+1 \mapsto p$

$$=\sum_{p=2}^{n+1}a^\bar{p-1}P_{a-p}(u)DuH_{p-1}^n(u) + \sum_{p=1}^{n}a^\bar{p-1}P_{a-p}(u)DH_p^n(u)$$

Using the properties of $H$, we can join the two summands into one

$$=\sum_{p=1}^{n+1}a^\bar{p-1}P_{a-p}(u)\left(DuH_{p-1}^n(u) + DH_p^n(u)\right)$$

By definition

$$D^{n+1}(P_a \circ u) = \sum_{p=1}^{n+1}(D^{p}P_{a-p} \circ u)H_{p}^{n+1}(u)=\sum_{p=1}^{n+1}a^\bar{p-1}P_{a-p}(u)\left(DuH_{p-1}^n(u) + DH_p^n(u)\right)$$

Would be true only if the hypothesis holds.

Also, for the case $p=1$:

$$H_1^{n+1}(u) = DuH_{0}^n(u)+DH_1^n(u) = (Du)(0) + D(D^n u) = D^{n+1} u$$

---

For the general case, a similar set of steps can be applied until we reach

$$D^{n+1}(f \circ u) = D\left(\sum_{p=1}^{n}(D^pf \circ u)H_p^n(u)\right)$$
$$ = \sum_{p=1}^{n+1}(D_pf \circ u)\left(DuH_{p-1}^{n}(u) + DH_p^n(u)\right)$$
$$ = \sum_{p=1}^{n+1}(D_pf \circ u)H_p^{n+1}$$

And also,

$$D^{1}(f \circ u) = (D^1f \circ u)H_1^1(u) = (D^1f \circ u)D(u)$$

Comment: The requirements on $H_p^n(u)$ says absolutely nothing about values of $p > 1$ and $< n$. It even specifies what $H$ should be for $p = 0$ and $n+1$ even though those values of $p$ do not occur in the formula, but for most of the values of $p$, it could be anything at all. Did you mistranscribe the actual conditions?

Comment: The cases for $p=0, n+1$ are just for convenience to include these indexes in the sum since they are zero. I wanted to get the other terms from the expression $D^n(P_a \circ u) = \sum_{p=1}^{n}(D^{p}P_{a-p} \circ u)H_{p}^{n}(u)$ and the recursion $H_p^{n+1}(u) = DuH_{p-1}^n(u)+DH_p^n(u)$.